# Firefox plugin to download audio while playing youtube video

Tags: firefox

I want to know if there is a firefox plugin that will automatically download the audio of a livestreaming video preferably for youtube.

If not audio, I need it at least for video download. Is there such a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

For something automated like you're talking about, you might want to look for a greasemonkey script or make one yourself. However, I used this alot:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/

When you're on a page where it can download the video for you, the little icon animates and you're one-click away from a seamless video download.

Comment: I'd like to point out that to convert downloads to audio only on Windows using downloadhelper, you have to register, for which a fee is payable(note Windows only - any other OS its free). I normally use Debian, but I've just found this out after attempting to download & convert to MP3 on a Windows machine @ work